# Mail O365 message trace report to extenal user

Tags: microsoft-office-365, exchangeonline

I'm using O365's new Security & Compliance portal to create a message trace.  I'd like to create an "Enhanced Summary Report" which creates a CSV file and mails the link once created.  When I try to add an external mail address the error:
[image]

Given I'm an external party providing support to this client, I don't have an internal mailbox/address in their tenant that I can mail said link to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Microsoft:

The available report types are:

Summary: Available if the time range is less than 10 days, and requires no additional filtering options. The results are available almost immediately after you click Search.

Enhanced summary or Extended: These reports are only available as downloadable CSV files, and require one or more of the following filtering options regardless of the time range: By these people, To these people, or Message ID. You can use wildcards for the senders or the recipients (for example, *@contoso.com).

Notes:

Enhanced summary and Extended reports are prepared using archived message trace data, and it can take up to several hours before your report is available to download. Depending on how many other Office 365 admins have also submitted report requests around the same time, you may also notice a delay before your queued request starts to be processed.

While you can select an Enhanced summary or Extended report for any date/time range, commonly the last four hours of archived data will not yet be available for these two types of reports.

**When you click Next, you're presented with a summary page that lists the filtering options that you selected, a unique (editable) title for the report, and the email address that receives the notification when the message trace completes (also editable, and must be in one of your organization's accepted domains).** Click Prepare report to submit the message trace. On the main Message trace page, you can see the status of the report in the Downloadable reports section.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/message-trace-in-the-office-365-security-compliance-center-3e64f99d-ac33-4aba-91c5-9cb4ca476803?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#EnhancedSummaryReport

Comment: Thanks. Not the answer I wanted but a valid answer nonetheless.